# Permission error when importing certificate to cacerts

Tags: java, authentication, keytool

I need to import a certificate for some maven repositories into the global keystore. 
The certificate file is named maven.crt so the command I am running is

```
keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -alias maven -file maven.crt
```

It asks me for password and then if I trust the certificate to which I answer yes
This is the final output

```
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts (Not a directory)
```

I ran this command as root so I don't know why I am receiving permissions error here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your path is wrong. cacerts file is in jdk_directory/jre/lib/security.

Try this instead:

```
keytool -import -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -alias maven -file maven.crt
```

Comment: ... embarrassing! Thanks for this

Comment: @Ernestas Is this the right path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security ?

Comment: @AkshayrajKore I don't use Mac, but it looks a bit odd for me... Why do you have /Contents/Home in your JDK directory?

Comment: @ErnestasKardzys That simply seems to be the way it is structured on Mac. Using /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts worked just fine for me.

Comment: I had issues getting the path on ubuntu; 
echo `$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')`
Works well for grabbing where home is 
Then its simply /lib/security/cacerts on the end :)

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo chmod -R 777 /jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/security/cacerts
2. keytool -import -alias -aliasCertificate -file pathToCertifcate.crt -keystore /jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/security/cacerts
3. sudo chmod -R 644 java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/lib/security/cacerts